# How to download file from ADLS in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a scenario to download a file from ADLS Gen2 and then process the data using wso2
I see there is a connector in wso2 but it has only listing, uploading, creating, and deleting options.
Nothing to download files.
Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

If the Download operation is not available you can consider writing your own [Class Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/class-Mediator/) to implement the functionality.

Comment: Thank you. yes right now I am trying to do the same thing.